# X11 forwarding from Linux to Mac has some corrupted fonts

Tags: centos, ssh, mac, xorg

Setup is a Mac running macOS 10.13.4 and XQuartz 2.7.11, with CentOS 7.4 running in VMware.

When I ssh from the Mac into the VM and launch Chromium 61, something strange happens.

Here's a screenshot of me visiting www.heise.de, any idea what's going on and how to fix it?

[image: Example of Font corruption]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same problem once. Try connecting again after installing this package.

```
yum install dejavu-lgc-sans-fonts
```